# Custom ImageDataGenerator() for half a million images where labels and pixels are in 2 separate DataFrames using Keras (or any other library)

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, keras, neural-network

I have 2 separate `DataFrames` which contains pieces of information for around half a million images summing upto 6+ GBs. There are 4 `.parquet` files which I had to `pd.concat()` one by one to make a new DataFrame `imgs` containing the pixels of `137*236`, values ranging from `0-32331` and the image's id column.

```
imgs
>>
          image_id     0      1  ...  32330  32331

0       Train_50210  246    253  ...    251    250   
1       Train_50211  250    245  ...    241    244
...                              ...
...                              ...
...                              ...
453651  Train_50210    0    253  ...    251    250   
453652  Train_50211  250    245  ...    241    244
```

The second `csv` contains the image's labels and the values of three different classes that each image belongs to. I imported the csv in `train`.

```
train
>>

            image_id      class_1   class_2  class_3    

0            Train_5           15         9        5    
1            Train_1          159         0        0
...
...
...
453651  Train_342524             0       15       34
453652    Train_9534            18        0        7
```

Number of rows in `train` are equal to rows in `imgs`. It means that the Y-Labels of the images are stored in `train` and the corresponding pixel attributes are in `imgs`

I tried merging both the the dataframes using `pd.merge(imgs,train,on='image_id').drop('image_id')` and **It took a long time and my kernal died every time while processing the above 2 steps. Please do suggest an alternate approach if there is any**

Could somebody please tell me how to make a custom Data Generator for

```
1. producing batches of images
2. Augmented images for robustness
```

using `keras` or any other library for fast processing.

**Alternatively, could someone please tell me how to use ImageDataGenerator().flow() in my case**

Comment: Can you share more of your program, and maybe some data? It's difficult to do anything with so little information.

Comment: This is all the data that I have. I'll start building a NN model once I am able to load the data properly but the problem is with data loading itself. it's a data of over 6 GBs and crashes my kernal everytime I merge the two dataframes

Comment: Then can you provide some information on the data, alongside the code?

Comment: `pd.merge(imgs,trainon='image_id').drop('image_id')` is just a typo or this is your actual code? I mean `trainon='image_id'` is actually `train, on='image_id'`?

Comment: @Geeocode Sorry! that was just a typo. Can you please my comment below to help me with the situation on the dataset.

Comment: @AMC - My dataframe has 32333 columns. First one is ```image_id```. From first to last columns, these are numbered from ```0-32331``` that makes 32332 columns which represents the total pixels of a ```137*236``` image. There are around millions of images so total number of rows in my ```imgs``` dataframe is around half a million. Second Dataframe contains the ```Y``` labels of these images. I want to load these images to my Neural Network after augmentation. How could I using ```ImageDataGenerator()```??

Comment: Why do you want to merge the labels and the data dataframe?

Comment: These are un ordered. So I'll have to search for the labels everytime I want a something. Sorting will create a pattern I think so just being careful. And let's just suppose I use them separately, how could I load them using ```ImageDataGenerator``` via two different DataFrames? @Geeocode

Comment: I see that your dataset unordered, but the dataset aligned with the labels i.e. has the same order?

Comment: Yes it has same order. Every image is correctly aligned to its id,label, pixels in their respective dataframes @Geeocode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205379/discussion-between-geeocode-and-deshwal).

Comment: If the CSV fits your memory, the images as numpy will probably fit too, then you just follow the example here: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html Try this to get it into numpy array and then array.resize that should work

Answer (score 2):

This is what i would suggest, load the dataframe, piece by piece, do not load the entirety of it at the same time, this might actually exceed your RAM, hence the dying kernel.

Then iterate through the dataframe line by line, take the 32332 columns, and reshape them into an image of 137x236 and save them to disk with a the appropriate name in to the folder train_data/class_number/, you can then use keras ImageDataGenerator().flowfromDirectory()

<strike>the issue is that the 32332 columns dont make sense to me, if the image was a single channel 137x236 image, then the number of columns would be 137*236 = 29972.So theres like 2k columns unaccounted for. Are you sure of the format of the data?</strike>

Comment: I think there might be some misunderstanding. 137*236=32332

Comment: and the proces of saving half a million images on disk to iterate them again doesn't make sense. As far as I know, the ```ImageDataGenerator``` will eventually convert these images in array of 137*236 under the hood. I just don't know how to load that array and use it for model.

Comment: my bad, idk what i was calculating, anyways, that being said you can just write a custom generator and use fit_generator

Comment: also i would suggest breaking the files down into much more manageable forms, its not recommended to load large amounts of data into the RAM

Comment: for more info you may refer to https://towardsdatascience.com/writing-custom-keras-generators-fe815d992c5a

Comment: How can I write a custom generator? P.S-> How can I use these multi ```y-labels``` to use in flow?

Comment: @Deshwal _How can I write a custom generator? P.S-> How can I use these multi y-labels to use in flow?_ That's a question whose answer can be found in the documentation, guides and tutorials, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: it is as @AMC said, i cannot explain how to write a custom generator over SO for simple reasons like the fact that it is entirely dependent on your own problem, the medium article i have linked above is a very good source on how to do that, i suggest you give that a read, it really isnt difficult

Comment: I agree with you but the very issue is that using a custom generator, you can miss few things (atleast I might) and it may not be very good regarding performance vise. Can we modify/alter the original ```flow``` so that it accepts multi-output values?